# Warnings When Starting JDeveloper 12c

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper

I am getting the following warnings every time I start JDeveloper 12c.  Does anyone have any info about what may be causing them and how to correct the problem?  Do I need to be worried about them?

Thanks,

Mar 24, 2015 4:35:10 PM oracle.jdeveloper.credential.model.CredentialInfoImpl decodePwdToCharArray

WARNING: A problem has been found decoding the password. Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Mar 24, 2015 4:35:10 PM oracle.jdeveloper.credential.model.CredentialInfoImpl decodePwdToCharArray

WARNING: A problem has been found decoding the password. Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling Oracle SSO on the PC has fixed this in the past.  Others have also mentioned that antivirus online scanning can also cause it (temporarily disable while using Jdeveloper).